# Plotly Python format Time Axis to HH:MM issues

Tags: python, datetime, plotly

I tried many things, but the X-axis on plotly, which contains times in the format of HH:MM:SS in a pandas dataframe doesn't want to change.

I tried the following:

- Trying to change the datatype of the dataframe column to pydatetime
- adding the pydates to a list and applying strftime with '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' (to convert it later) and '%H:%M:%S'
- tried the basic stuff with tickformat="%H:%M" in fig.update_xaxes - Method
- and tickformat='%H:%M' in fig.update_layout - Method (also with dictionary) for xaxis parameter
- also tried this: fig.layout['xaxis_tickformat'] = "%H:%M"
- also tried to apply the dates to strftime with "%H:%M" but the values are a type of aggregated than (or only one value for the certain minute is picked)

The results change: Sometimes all datapoints disappear (they are on the left or right corner) and if they not disappear, the x-axis shows the values for 15:23:01 for example.

Below is a code snippet of my method:

```
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

dates = pd.to_datetime(dataframe.Time, format='%H:%M:%S')

dates = dates.dt.to_pydatetime()
datelist = []
for date in dates:
    date = datetime.datetime.strftime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    datelist.append(date)
# dates['Time'] = pd.Series(dates, dtype=object)

# dates = dates.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
print(dataframe.Time)

print(dates)
df = dataframe
# also tried here with x = dataframe.Time with same results
fig = px.line(df, x=datelist, y=["Foo1", "Foo2"], title='Foo')

# changing Y-Axis ticks to 10 minutes
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=45,
                 # type="date",
                 tickmode='array',
                 tickformat="%H:%M",
                 tickvals=df["Time"][0::600])

fig.update_layout(
    title="Foo", title_x=0.5,
    xaxis_title="Time",
    xaxis=dict(
        tickformat='%H:%M'
    ),
    # xaxis_tickformat = "%H:%M",
    yaxis_title="<i>g</i>",
    legend_title="Sensor",
    font=dict(
        family="Courier New, monospace",
        size=50,
        color="RebeccaPurple"
    )
)

# fig.layout['xaxis_tickformat'] = "%H:%M"

fig.show()
```

I hope you can help me as I followed the instructions on the plotly website and googled, but plotly stuff seems to be rare.

Thanks in advice, I can provide more infos if needed.